# Energy from fission of Pb?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

The fission of lead has been demonstrated as a result of proton or photon bombardment. The process releases energy from the mass defect between the original Pb nucleus and the fission products.

Recently, nuclear reactors operating in a subcritical mode where fission is driven by particle bombardment have been explored (with some being constructed).

What gets in the way of using Pb as a potential future nuclear fuel in an accelerator-driven, subcritical nuclear reactor?

Comment: Have you considered the threshold energy input needed by the incident particle to cause fission? What the cross section for fission by such particles is? And the energy to generate such particles?

Comment: Echoing @JonCuster, you generally never want to use protons to generate nuclear fission because they are electrically charged, and therefore need to overcome the massive electromagnetic repulsion with the  nucleus in order to get close enough to produce the reaction. This barrier is known as the Coulomb barrier. Neutrons are electrically neutral, so they don't have this massive suppression.

Comment: Also, your second paragraph seems odd. All  nuclear reactors operate by fission reactions which are driven by particle (neutron) bombardment. Are you emphasizing the fact that lead could be a good candidate for a **sub-critical** nuclear reactor?

Comment: Finally, were there any sources (videos, articles, etc.) from which you got this information? If so, could you provide them?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan - note that some EDNA machines have, in fact, used protons (although some then use those for neutron spallation). Nowhere did I mention protons. I'll note that making energetic (>1MeV) neutrons often means making a bunch of even higher energy protons/alphas/whatnot.

Comment: @JonCuster My bad, I had presumed you were primarily hinting at the Coulomb barrier and correspondingly low reaction cross-sections.

Comment: There are no neutron-driven fission cross section data reported on ENDF for Pb-204, 206 ,207, or 208.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan - a fun historical fact, the first human-controlled nuclear reaction was the 7Li(p,$\alpha$)$\alpha$ reaction by Cockroft and Walton.

Comment: Although fission of Pb is used in nuclear physics studies, such as https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0090375214006103 where 500 A MeV Pb-208 impacts onto hydrogen or deuterium. Synchrotron beams are not energy-efficient to make...

Comment: @JonCuster I just read about that, quite interesting! But for a potential nuclear power plant, I can't see how lead could be a better, more economical choice than some other nuclear fuel, for all the reasons that have come up so far. That's the point I had in mind.

Comment: Thank you all. From looking at a few papers online my sense was that the cross section for neutron induced fission of Pb was too low. However, there has been a literature recently that discusses the modification of fission cross sections with strong and fast laser pulses. As for the economics, clearly U is better but Pb would be much more widely acceptable if it ever became a possibility. The other interesting aspect here is that accelerators are rapidly becoming smaller and cheaper (see laser-plasma accelerators). As mentioned, protons can be turned into neutrons via a target.